# Getting all fields in form_tag without attribute name in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails. When page loads, it displays a form with text boxes having some value in it and at the same time allows the user to enter a new value in those text boxes.

Below is my view template code:

```
<%= form_tag("/myapp/rewriteScores", :method=>'post') do %>
  <% for region_score in scores_row %>
     <%= text_field_tag 'scores',region_score.at(1),class: 'scoreValues' %>
     <%= submit_tag("Submit Values") %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Now when the user submits the form with new values, how can I get those values in the controller?

**Please note:**
Here since I'm printing the values in loop ,all the input tags will have same attribute name and class name.

Comment: if your attributes will have same name it will give you last attribute only in controller. You cannot pass all fields with same name.

Comment: `scores_row.each_with_index do |region_score, index|
<%= text_field_tag 'scores_#{index}',region_score.at(1),class: 'scoreValues' %>
<%end%>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<%= text_field_tag 'scores[]',region_score.at(1),class: 'scoreValues' %`

name your text_field_tag as 'scores[]'

In your controller you can get all the values

params["scores"] - This will be an array of values